# What is the file equivalent of .OBJ files for animation and bone data?

Tags: export, import, file-format

I am using three.js in javascript.

I have exported a mesh in a .OBJ file and I wanted to also export its bone and animation keyframe data. Since .OBJ files only contain v and f values, is there another *simple* file container that deals with bone/animation data?

e.g.

```
MyModel.OBJ
MyModelAnim.other_standard_anim_file_type
```

I would then like to open up the .OBJ file in blender, aswell as this second file, and combine the bones/anim data back onto the mesh.

So in javascript:

```
var fileObj = buildMyFileFromBoneAndAnimationData(scene.animationStuff, scene.boneStuff);
var blob = new Blob ( [ fileObj ], { type : "octet/stream" } );
downloadFile("filename.extension", blob)
```

Then open that file in blender and use anim/bone data to hook into a mesh.

Comment: Depends on what you consider simple and what your criteria for the file format are. The question is rarely if the file format is simple but rather if the target software supports it.

Comment: @rjg clarified! its going three.js --> blender

Comment: Try the BVH. That's for armature animation.

Comment: @FFeller it seems bvh isnt very well documented: https://blenderartists.org/t/i-dont-see-any-tutorial-on-how-to-make-bvh-files/658545 .  I would like to be able to build this file in javascript, save from browser then open in blender. I've updated question to give pseudo js code i'd like to do